# understanding gödel's 1931 paper - number theoritical formulae

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am reading a translation of Gödel's original paper about in completeness theorem and there are a couple things i don't understand.

Here is the document i am using primarily : http://www.research.ibm.com/people/h/hirzel/papers/canon00-goedel.pdf

I am just curious : In his system P, there is no symbol for addition/multiplication or any arithmetical formula, yet it is often mentionned "number-theoretical functions" or "number-theoretical formula", i guess they are "represented" by their extension type-n variables and signs.

But I guess there may not systematically be a formula for any classes of subsets of N representing a function/functionnal relation. Yet there is no symbols for arithmetic, then what about those "number-theoretical functions" or "number-theoretical formula" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The signs of system $P$ include $0$ and $\mathit{succ}$ (see the beginning of section 2.1 in your reference). These together with the logical apparatus in the system are enough to define any primitive recursive relation (see section 2.5).

Comment: Hello, sorry for answering late.
Actually, I'm also stuck with theorem 5, i bought the book from Peter Smith "Introduction to Godels theorems", i could get the idea of the proof sketch showing that systems at least as powreful as Robinson Arithmetic are primitive recursive adequate, but i can't figure out how to do it using Gödel's system.

Could you help me on that ?
Or show me or redirect me to some resources that could show me how to perform arithmetic or define PR relations/function using Gödel's system ? 

Thank you in advance